# deploy tomcat servlet project on heroku

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, heroku, webapp-runner

I have developed a tomcat-servlet based web application which I can run on my local machine nicely. I send it requests by posting a json to it:

```
"curl ontent-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"username":"Piran", "password":"123", "requestedUsername":"hsn.vahedi", "requestedPassword":"111", "role":"client", "firstName":"Hossein", "lastName":"Vahedi", "phoneNumber":"09212814194"}' localhost:8080/myApp/register"
```

and it gives me the correct json response. But when I deploy my application on heroku this way: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner and send it a request, it gives me this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Heroku | Welcome to your new app!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
      body {
        background-color: white;
        color: #333333;
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 36px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 14px; }

      .section {
        margin-bottom: 36px; }
        .section.friendly {
          color: #222222; }
          .section.friendly h1 {
            font-size: 26px;
            background-color: #dad8e4;
            padding: 18px 22px 15px 22px;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden; }
            .section.friendly h1 strong {
              display: inline-block;
              float: left; }
            .section.friendly h1 small {
              display: inline-block;
              float: right;
              text-align: right;
              font-size: 18px;
              padding-top: 4px;
              color: #333333; }
          .section.friendly .article {
            border: 4px solid #dad8e4;
            padding: 24px 18px 18px 18px; }
            .section.friendly .article h3 {
              font-size: 20px;
              margin: 0 0 18px 0; }
            .section.friendly .article a {
              color: #6b6ceb; }
              .section.friendly .article a:visited {
                color: #1d1d3b; }
            .section.friendly .article p {
              font-size: 14px; }
            .section.friendly .article ul {
              list-style-type: square; }
      .section.original {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        color: #444444; }
        .section.original h2 {
          background-color: #dddddd;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 18px 22px 18px 22px;
          font-size: 20px; }
        .section.original pre {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 18px 22px 18px 22px;
          overflow: auto;
          font-family: monaco, monospaced; }
          .section.original pre code {
            display: block;
            font-size: 11px;
            width: 100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='section friendly'>
            <h1><strong>Heroku | Welcome to your new app!</strong></h1>
            <div class='article'>
              <p>Refer to the <a href="//devcenter.heroku.com/">documentation</a> if you need help deploying.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What is the problem? thanks!

Comment: You didn't deploy your app correctly or used the wrong url so you see the default response from heroku.

Comment: @zapl The url is not wrong. I'm sure about that.

Comment: @zapl You were right. The app wasn't deploy correctly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found my problem's solution: http://searchsaya.blogea.me/look/Try_Git/Git_%E2%80%9Cbroken_Pipe%E2%80%9D_Error_When_Pushing_To_A_Repository/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cubHVrZWJlbm5ldHQuY29tLzIwMTEvMDcvMjUvZ2l0LWJyb2tlbi1waXBlLWVycm9yLXdoZW4tcHVzaGluZy10by1hLXJlcG9zaXRvcnkv_blog

It's about limits on the app's size!